# Send notification to another application

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications

I'm creating 2 applications, 
First is just like a `CRUD app` and the second one is a `Dashboard app`.

I have no problem when using this code below. 
But i can use this only in `CRUD app`.

```
notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "CRUD Application";
notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Employee has started new task." + 
                        Environment.NewLine + 
                        "Click here to check the task.";

notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

It is possible to send notification from `CRUD app` to `Dashboard app`?

For Eg. If I save a data using `CRUD app` it will notify to `Dashboard app`

Comment: The requirement can be satisfied using Self-hosted WCF, Selft-hosted WebAPI, Self-hosted SignalR, Event Queue/Message Bus, SQL Dependency, ...

Comment: Just to have an idea about it, take a look at this [WCF example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32694012/3110834).

Comment: Or [NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream) and [NamedPipeServerStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream), easy to setup, simplified functionality but quite efficient.